# PHP MySQL Yii - database reading not writing

Tags: php, mysql, yii, lamp

I have a working Yii app on my local lamp stack. Now when I put the app on a lamp server the app reads the db and runs, but the app isn't successfully writing to the db. I'm getting no errors logs. Any thoughts?

Here's how I'm updating the db:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    if ($_GET["yep"] == "") {
      pd_error("You are not logged in!");
    }
    list($uid, $domain) = preg_split("/@/",$_GET["yep"],2);
    $model=$this->loadModel($uid);
    $this->redirect($model->URL."?".$model->Unique_ID);     
}

public function loadModel($uid)
{
    $model=People::model()->findByPk($uid);
    $model->Login_Count++;
    $model->Last_Logged=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    if ($model->validate()) {
         $model->save();
    } else { 
        $this->render('notice');
    }
    return $model;
}
```

The weird thing is, even when the db doesn't update the Login_Count and Last_Logged the user still gets redirected to their url, so the sql must be valid because the notice page never loads. Any thoughts?

### Update + Solution

The problem ended up being that the mysql server had autocommit set to false. To override this at the app level add the following line to the config/main.php db array:

```
'db'=>array(
    ...
    'initSQLs'=>array('SET AUTOCOMMIT=1',),
    ...
);
```

[Yii: using active record with autocommit off on mysql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330815/yii-using-active-record-with-autocommit-off-on-mysql-server)

Comment: Did you make sure you the db user has `GRANT` for update/insert/delete on the database and tables in question? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html#grant-privileges

Comment: Yes the db user has those privileges

Comment: How are you writing to the DB? Any code snippet?

Comment: the validation is not successfull

Comment: wouldn't the notice page render then? Because it's not rendering, the page get's redirected to the model->url

Answer (score 0):

The rendering of `notice` page doesn't stop your redirect. It might be rendered, but you won't be able to see it because of redirect. Try to refactor your code.

- You're validating your model twice and the validation probably might be skipped since there's no data coming from App user.
- You don't check if `People` model actually found.
- There is `CWebUser::afterLogin` method which you can override to do this kind of stuff (update login count and last login date)

Maybe this way (quick fix) will work:

```
function actionIndex()
{
    if ($_GET["yep"] == "") {
      pd_error("You are not logged in!");
    }
    list($uid, $domain) = preg_split("/@/",$_GET["yep"],2);
    if (null === ($model=People::model()->findByPk($uid))
        throw new CHttpException(404);
    $model->Login_Count++;
    $model->Last_Logged=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    if ($model->save()) {
         $this->redirect($model->URL."?".$model->Unique_ID);
    } else {
        // echo CHtml::errorSummary($model)
        $this->render('notice');
    }       
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out that it was validating twice, but this didn't fix it