# Yii: using active record with autocommit off on mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii

Just wrote a Yii app and on the development mysql server the autocommit was set to true. Now when the app went into production I just realized that the mysql server autocommit is set to false. The app is using active record to save (which auto commits). Is there a variable that I can set in the config db file instead of having to add a beginTransaction and commit in each write to the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDbConnection has an [`autoCommit`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#autoCommit-detail) property. I haven't tested it yet though.

**EDIT** because of [PHP MySQL Yii - database reading not writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14288327/php-mysql-yii-database-reading-not-writing)

Try using [`CDbConnection::initSQLs`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#initSQLs-detail) and execute `SET AUTOCOMMIT=1` every time a connection is made.

```
'db'=>array(
    ...
    'initSQLs'=>array('SET AUTOCOMMIT=1',),
    ...
);
```